# How to delete all the lines that match specific condition

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have a number of pdb files and I want to keep only those lines that starts with `^FORMUL` and if line has `C` followed by the number that is larger then (`C3,C4,C5,C6..100 etc`) then I should not print it. Second condition is that within every line sum of `C, H and N` should be `>=` 6, then delete it

So overall delete the lines in which `C` is followed by number more then `2>` and sum of `C+O+N` is `>=` then 6.

```
FORMUL   3  HOH   *207(H2 O)    (print it)                                     
FORMUL   2  SF4    FE4 S4       (print it)                                                
FORMUL   3  NIC    C5 H7 N O7   (don't print, there is C5 and sum is more then 6)                                               
FORMUL   4  HOH   *321(H2 O)    (print it)                                                
FORMUL   3  HEM    2(C34 H32 FE N4 O4)  (don't print, there is C34)
```

I have tried to do it in `perl` but lines are soo diverse from each other so Im not sure if it is possible to do.

Over all these conditions chould be included together, meaning that all lines in which `C>2` and `sum>=6` should be deleted.
`C1 O5 N3` should be deleted; `C3 N1 01` should not be deleted although `C` is `3`.

In perl I don't know how to assign these two conditions. Here I wrote opposite situation not to delete but to print these lines if these two conditions are not met.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines; 
my $file;
my $line;
open ($file, '<', '5PCZ.pdb') or die $!; 
while (my $line = <$file>)
{
 if ($line =~ m/^FORMUL/)
{
  push (@lines, $line);   
}
}
close $file;
#print "@lines\n";


foreach $line(@lines) 
{
  if ($line eq /"C"(?=([0-2]))/ )
{
  elsif ($line eq "Sum of O,N & C is lt 6")

    print @lines    
}
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to do it in Perl, then add the Perl tag and show the code you have. Your description is very confused so I am not surprised you are having difficulty coding it. Maybe try and write 3 separate, simple rules either for keeping or for discarding rather than a rule that mixes things like you currently have...  *"I want to keep lines with FORMUL and if it has something else I don't want to keep it.".*

Comment: Thanks, I did it few days ago then I deleted it but I will write it now.. The thing is that I am pretty unskilled with manipulating with lines. I can include in the script like read file, read each line till the end, if it starts with `^FORMUL` then I have a problem to assign conditions and to delete lines id they do not meet these conditions.

Comment: @djordje, what if there is no `C` char but `N22` is presented?

Comment: Then I should not delete it: so delete all lines that have `C>2` (C3,C4,C5..) and sum of `CON` has to be `=>`. So line that has `C1 N22 O1` should be deleted although `sum` is more then `6`, `C` is less then `2`. If `C3 N1 O1` this should also not be included

Comment: I edited the question including the perl script that I just wrote, but I am having a real trouble to assign these two conditions (having gaps in my regular expression knowledge).

Comment: You say the two conditions are inclusive, right?  How come the line with C1 O5 N3 should be deleted?

Comment: because `C<2`.  It has to support both conditions. If within this sum `C` is `1` or `2`, then I cannot use it. Only `C3 NX OX` in which `sum` is more or equal to 6 then delete them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a cross-site duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183135/how-to-delete-all-the-lines-that-match-specific-condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, it's probably easier to write this as a filter that prints the lines that you want to keep. I've also written this following the Unix Filter Model (reads from `STDIN`, writes to `STDOUT`) as that makes the program far more flexible (and, interestingly, easier to write!)

Assuming that you're running the program on Linux (or similar) and that your code is in an executable file called `my_filter` (I recommend a more descriptive name!) then you would call it like this:

```
$ my_filter < 5PCZ.pdb > 5PCZ.pdb.new
```

The code would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) { # read from STDIN a line at a time
  # Split data on whitespace, but only into four columns
  my @cols = split /\s+/, $_, 4;

  next unless $cols[0] eq 'FORMUL';

  # Now extract the letter stuff into a hash for easy access.
  # We extract letters from the final column in the record.
  my %letters = $cols[-1] =~ m/([A-Z])(\d+)/g;

  # Give the values we're interested in, a default of 0
  $letters{$_} //= 0 for (qw[C O N]);

  next if $letters{C} > 2
    and $letters{C} + $letters{O} + $letters{N} >= 6;

  # I think we can then print the line;
  print;
}
```

This seems to give the correct output for your sample data. And I hope the comments make it obvious how to tweak the conditions.

Comment: Dave: Thank You for this answer. Yeah I also realized that it is much simpler to print lines that I want to keep. Comment make it more very understandable! I have to practice much more to switch mindset from biology to programming. Cheers

Comment: @Dave, the people at [ubuntu.se] like [your solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/994248/504066) ;-)

Comment: @PerlDuck: Oh, well, **isn't** that interesting! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Extended **`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' \
    '/^FORMUL/{ 
         if ($4 !~ /\<C/) print; 
         else { 
             match($4, /\<C[0-9]+/); 
             c=substr($4, RSTART+1, RLENGTH); 
             if (c > 2) next; 
             else { 
                 match($4, /\<O[0-9]+/); 
                 o=substr($4, RSTART+1, RLENGTH); 
                 match($4, /\<N[0-9]+/); 
                 n=substr($4, RSTART+1, RLENGTH); 
                 if (c+o+n < 6) print 
             }
         } 
     }' 5PCZ.pdb
```

The output:

```
FORMUL   3  HOH   *207(H2 O)
FORMUL   2  SF4    FE4 S4
FORMUL   4  HOH   *321(H2 O)
```